# Woocommerce success message not displaying in IE, Firefox or Safari

Tags: php, html, wordpress, cross-browser, woocommerce

I have a product page for a client that works great. The only problem is when someone adds something to a cart, the success message "View Cart .... has been added to your cart" only appears in Chrome, but not in Firefox, IE or Safari. Anyone has a fix?

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: this happen for many reason so please better you upgrade plugins, theme,woocommerce, and wordpress to their latest version